VBA runs in VBA but not as assigned to a Quick Access Button in Outlook
Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code (and how to fix it) I built in the VBA module window in Outlook? It runs fine when I click on an emhttps://stackoverflow.com/editing-helpail and then click the green "run" button in the VBA window. I assigned the module to a button in the Outlook Quick Access Toolbar and nothing happens at all. Nothing happens when I click on the macro in the Developer tab in the Macros section. Note: I have already enabled (long before) the "Enable all macros" option.
Sub Done()

    Dim MyMailItem As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set MyMailItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End If

    If (ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 1) And _
          (ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Class = olMail) Then

            Set MyMailItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    End If

    MyMailItem.FlagRequest = "DONE"

    MyMailItem.Save

End Sub

I assigned the module to a button in the Outlook Quick Access Toolbar and nothing happens at all. Nothing happens when I click on the macro in the Developer tab in the Macros section.
The code should have marked the email with a custom followup flag with the text "DONE".

Try to get rid of the On Error Resume Next statement and see if you get an error.

Verify only one instance of  Sub Done() and Module name is not Done.
